# Sort entities based on a substring

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am using EntityFramework 5 with Code First.

Please have a look at the following POCO.

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name {get; set; }  // e.g. en=Screwdriver;de=Schraubenzieher;fr=Tournevis

    /// <summary>
    /// This will always return a valid string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="languageCode"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string GetLocalizedName(string languageCode)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

As you can see, each product has a "multi language" name which contains all the different translations within this one string.

I can't figure out an easy way to sort the products by a certain language with LINQ. The code I am looking for should look like this (assuming I want a sorted collection based on the English name):

```
var sortedProducts = from p in Context.Products
                     orderby p.GetLocalizedName("en")
                     select p;
```

But this won't work as soon as I iterate over the items e.g. with .ToList(): *"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String GetLocalizedName(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."*

Does anybody have an elegant idea on how to solve this? The result must be an IQueryable of type Product again (if there is no other way i could live with a List of products too).

Thanks guys!

Comment: You can't use your .NET method in Linq2Entity directly. Can you share the code of `GetLocalizedName`?

Comment: Honestly, I think this is the wrong way to go around localisation.  I think you should have a translation table that would have `prodScrewDriver` in it, and mappings for the various cultures.  Then, your `Name` method merely returns `prodScrewDriver` and the interface translates it appropriately.

Comment: The name of the product contains all available languages at all time?

Comment: Thanks guys. Yes, of course going with a separate language table would be the normal way to do it. But in this case I didn't have this option. That's why I had to come up with this multilanguage string. Didn't expect you would be concerned with this more than with my query problem ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The result must be an IQueryable of type Product again

That's not going to work. `string GetLocalizedName()` is a C# method, that's why you get the `cannot be translated into a store expression` error.

> (if there is no other way i could live with a List of products too).

Currently, you will need to do that:

```
  var sortedProducts = from p in Context.Products
                 .ToList()    // switch to IEnumerable and suffer the loss in performance
                 orderby p.GetLocalizedName("en")
                 select p;
```

The alternatives:

- implement `GetLocalizedName()` as a stored procedure and fix the mapping
- restructure your data model. Add a  `{ ProductId, LanguageCode, Description }` table.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, that the ordering will be done on client side.

```
var sortedProducts = (from p in Context.Products
                 select p)
                 .AsEnumerable()
                 .OrderBy(p => p.GetLocalizedName("en"));
```

Comment: if you mean this post, yes. so what?

Answer (score 1):

I think managing translations with one name, would be a hell of a job to manage.
I would split the language names in a master-detail:

```
string code = "de";

var sortedProducts = from p in Context.Products
                     join l in Context.ProductNames on p.id equals l.product_id
                     where l.languageCode == code 
                     // you can uncomment the code below to get the english always if the translation in 'code' (german) isn't available, but you need to eliminate duplicates.
                     // || l.languageCode == "en"
                     orderby l.localizedName
                     select new { p.id, p.whatever, l.localizedName };
```

This way the query is executed server-side.
And you can write queries to look for untranslated Names.

Comment: Hi Jeroen, thank you very much for your suggestions. But in my case, using a single multilanguage string actually saves me from doing a "hell of a job". But this is due to the context and too big of a story to tell here. So, thanks again.